# Onchange multiple select how to sum up the total in other input value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a select option with `onchange` function that can change the value in other input whenever I click the option.

However it is not working on multiple select which just only show the first select option value only when select many of the option.

HTML select option code

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="selectFunction(event)" 
name="pay_course[]" required="" multiple>

  <option data-typeid="1111" value="courseId1">courseName1</option>
  <option data-typeid="2222" value="courseId2">courseName2</option>
</select>
```

Input to be display the total

```
<input type="number" value="" id="money" class="form-control">
```

Function script

```
<script>
function selectFunction(e) {
  var type_id = $('select option:selected').attr('data-typeid'); //to get value
  document.getElementById("money").value =type_id;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When multiple options are selected then we need to loop through all the selected options and get the `data-typeid` for each of them using `map` like:

```js
function selectFunction(e) {
  var type_id = $('select option:selected').map(function() {
      return $(this).attr('data-typeid');
    })
    .get().map(parseFloat).reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b
    });
  console.log(type_id)
  $("#money").val( type_id );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" onchange="selectFunction(event)" name="pay_course[]" required="" multiple>

  <option data-typeid="1000" value="courseId1">courseName1  </option>
  <option data-typeid="2000" value="courseId2">courseName2  </option>
  <option data-typeid="3000" value="courseId3">courseName3  </option>
  <option data-typeid="4000" value="courseId4">courseName4  </option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="number" value="" id="money" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Below script:

```
   <script>
        function selectFunction(e) {
            var totalMoney = 0; 
            $('select option:selected').each(function(){
               totalMoney += parseInt($(this).attr('data-typeid'));
            });
            $("#money").val(totalMoney);
        }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a couple of options here.

first: if you can change

```
    <option data-typeid="1111" value="courseId1">courseName1</option>
```

to be

```
    <option data-typeid="1111" value="1111">courseName1</option>
```

so that the value will be "1111" instead then you could simply call $("select").val() and that will give you a comma separated string of values of all selected items.

second: if you really need the value to be the same as the text that is shown the you could do

```
    $("select option:selected").each(function() { 
      var type_id = $(this).attr('data-typeid');
      //your code here
    }
```

with this you could append one value at a time to the other input or sum them up or whatever.